# Not catching on key up event

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a flash component TextInput within a movieclip, added to stage, through as3.
The moment this mc is added to stage, it assigns keyboard event (key down and key up events), to the main stage (main app stage), and set main stage focus to main stage.

So far so good.

The problem is, when I type ENTER, I catch KEY_DOWN, but when I release key ENTER, my KEY_UP event is uncatched by my function assigned to that event.

Any body knows why?

It only works if I click the flash player.

---

(Code provided in comment)

```
private function initAdded(e:Event){ 
    _main.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,checkKeysDown); 
    _main.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,checkKeysUp); 
    MovieClip(_main).setStageFocus() 
} 

private function checkKeysDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void { 
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
        trace('enter down') 
    } 
} 

private function checkKeysUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void { 
    if(e.keyCode == 13){ 
        trace('enter up') 
    } 
}
```

Comment: We need to at least see: addEventListener code, listener functions

Comment: private function initAdded(e:Event){
   
   _main.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,checkKeysDown);
   _main.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,checkKeysUp);
   MovieClip(_main).setStageFocus()
   
  }
private function checkKeysDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
  {
   if (e.keyCode == 13)
   { trace('enter down')
                         }
                 }
private function checkKeysUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
  {
   if(e.keyCode==13){
                             trace('enter up')
                        }
                 }

Comment: if you place trace(_main.stage.focus) on key down it traces object Stage

Comment: Have you tried adding `MovieClip(_main).setStageFocus()` into your keysdown listener? It seems like a strange problem.

Comment: Even if main stage focus is main stage, KEY_UP won´t catch

Comment: I´ve tried to add MovieClip(_main).setStageFocus() didn´t work

Comment: I think the problem is the key ENTER, the other keys work

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that the KEY_UP event is being handled by the text area you are typing in, and it doesn't want to share, so it kills the event. Try:

```
_main.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,checkKeysUp, true);
```

This causes your event listener to catch the event in the capture phase, before the other event listener cancels propagation of the event.

Comment: The KEY_UP is being handled by the main stage

Comment: When the movie loads, even if I don´t type anything, but ENTER, the KEY_UP event function is not called

Comment: I'm talking about internally, not your code. Internally the text area is listening to those events, otherwise the text wouldn't be there. I'm saying it might internally treat the ENTER press differently, and then event.stopPropagation() when its done with it, preventing you from listening for it in the bubbling phase.

Comment: The event function for KEY_UP is not called when when pressed ENTER

Comment: @MarceloNoronha Did you try my solution?

Comment: _main.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,checkKeysUp, true);
doesn´t work

Comment: Actually what I want is:

Set the stage.focus to the TextInput so the user can type numbers and then when user finished typing his number, press ENTER and then calls a function on KEY_UP

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble helping you with this one.